# WPF change a tooltip background in c# code

Tags: c#, wpf, tooltip

I know how to change the tooltip in the xaml side of things, but does anybody know a great solution to do this in C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say you have a button like this:

```
    <Button x:Name="btnOne" Content="How to grow big and strong?">
        <Button.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip>
                Eat your veggies
            </ToolTip>
        </Button.ToolTip>
    </Button>
```

you can change it like this:

```
    var tip = ToolTipService.GetToolTip(this.btnOne) as ToolTip;
    tip.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Magenta);
```

Comment: I didnt know of the ToolTipService.GetToolTip . Thanks!